# Is network upgrade v15 still happening on Jul 16?

Tags: monerod, development

The release of 0.18 node software was supposed to occur on Jun 16, but I haven't seen any indication that occurred. What is the current status of the network upgrade and the software release?

Answer (score 3):

The network upgrade is currently planned for ~August 13. Thus, it has been delayed by approximately a month, see:

> Note: This blog post has been updated to reflect the new hard-fork date of the 13th of August, 2022, as the release was delayed due to required multi-sig security fixes and hardware wallet-related delays.

https://www.getmonero.org/2022/04/20/network-upgrade-july-2022.html

https://twitter.com/monero/status/1542883417804754945